# My formula for total and area is not calculating

Tags: c, syntax, decimal, formula, calculation

So in the project I'm doing I have a circle centered at the origin and I need to cut a vertical line through it. I'm trying to calculate the area of the smaller ratio of the circle; my inputs are the radius and the left and right hand ratio. for now I'm just trying to make sure it's doing my calculations correctly, and it is calculating the ratio properly, but its not calculating the ratio area at all. please help

```
int main(){
float radius, left, right, total;
float ratio;
float ratioArea = ratio*pi*pow(radius, 2);

scanf("%d%d%d", &radius, &left, &right);

if(left == right)
{
    printf("left and right are equal");
}

// do area calculations with righthand side
else if(left > right)
{
    ratio = right / (right+left);
    ratioArea = ratio * pi * pow(radius, 2);

    printf("ratio= %.6f, area = %f\n", ratio, ratioArea);

}

// do area calculations with lefthand side
else if(left < right)
{   
    ratio = left / (left + right);
    ratioArea = ratio*pi*pow(radius, 2);

    printf("ratio = %.6f, area = %f\n", ratio, ratioArea);
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: In `scanf` the `%d` format is for `int` but you are using `float` which should have `%f`.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and save time.  `scanf("%d%d%d", &radius, &left, &right);` will warn with a well enabled compiler.

Comment: Aside: using `pow` to square a number is inefficient - better to use `radius * radius`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Note that `pow(some_float,2)` will yield a `double` precision calculation while `some_float*some_float` remains `float`.  Even comparing `pow(some_double, 2)` to `some_double*some_double` can emit the same code with an optimizing compiler.  Still your idea is prudent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is here:

```
scanf("%d%d%d", &radius, &left, &right);
```

`%d` reads an integer and takes an `int *`, not a `float *`. You need `%f` to scan a `float`.

You also need to check whether `scanf` was successful:

```
if (scanf("%f%f%f", &radius, &left, &right) != 3) {
    // handle error here
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`scanf` returns the number of successfully scanned items. If the return value is not 3, at least one of your variables was not set.

---

A second (mostly harmless) problem:

```
float radius, left, right, total;
float ratio;
float ratioArea = ratio*pi*pow(radius, 2);
```

You're initializing `ratioArea` based on the values of `ratio` and `radius`, which are uninitialized at this point. I'm pretty sure this code has undefined behavior.

Just remove the initialization and do `float ratioArea;` instead; you already set `ratioArea` in each branch where you use it below.

Comment: OP's initial `float ratioArea = ratio*pi*pow(radius, 2);` is interesting too.

Comment: thank you. I fixed where i set up the formula for area and that worked but I think the major issue was the scanf. I knew it was something obvious like %f instead of %d and i went over all of my parameters multiple times to see if I had done that anywhere and completely glossed over it lol.